# How to use command line arguments as Scanner parameter in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program that requires that I use java command line arguments to open a file and find some information within that file. The files we want to access already exist in my projects file directory. The way I am trying to access them is by using the `Scanner` and just passing `args[0]` which should be the name of the file that we are trying to access.

Below is the code that I have come up with so far. Right now my code will always throw

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: {The Files Name} (The system cannot find the file specified)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File inputedFile = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(inputedFile);
        while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String fileData = fileReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(fileData);
        }
        fileReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred when trying to open the file.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I believe the reason I am getting this exception is because Java is not able to find the file off of just the file's name. Java needs the location of the file on my system for it to work so for example:

```
D:\coding-stuff\Java\CS-2420\src\comprehensive\super_simple.txt
```

would work while

```
super_simple.txt
```

would not.

This is an issue for me because I need this code to be run on multiple machines not just my own. So my question is how can I create a "relative link" to the file within my file structure?

Comment: I think you should provide the full path on the command line

Comment: It would make things a lot simpler but this is for a class assignment and our professor said that we will only be provided the name of the file and not the path.

Comment: Java deals with relative paths just fine. `new Scanner("foo.txt")` will open the file 'foo.txt', _if_ it is in the same directory as where you start the java process in. Same as all other command line tools. Try printing `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` to show where that is.

Comment: or you could just modified the System.in. `java program.java < *path to input*`

Comment: When your professor runs this code, presumably he or she will provide the correct path, either relative or absolute. You shouldn't need to worry about that.

Comment: _"The files we want to access already exist in my projects file directory. "_: The _file name_ and the _projects file directory_ are two different sets of info. Are you sure you are accepting the file name only? May be the projects file directory is same on all systems (and this may be relative to your working directory). Some concepts about files you need to be clear about are the present working directory, absolute paths and relative paths - and how they apply to your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Either you know the location of the file or you can obtain the location of the file or you can search for the file.

The [System](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html) properties contain the path to the working directory, the user's home directory and the temporary directory, so you could place your file in one of those three. Alternatively, you can use the `-D` option of the [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html) command to define your own [System] property.

You could also define an environment variable and obtain its value via method [getenv](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getenv()).

Another option would be to make the file a [resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

If you don't know or can't obtain the path to the file, then you can [search](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) for it, either using the Java API or, via class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), execute an operating system command to search for the file. [Note that the `System` properties can also tell you the host operating system.]